# Using join to append two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, I am trying to create some key-value pairs in a dictionary where the first element is a name and the second element is a dataframe.

```
# Creating a dictionary
data = {'Value':[0,0,0]}
kernel_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['M1','M2','M3'])
dict = {'dummy':kernel_df}
# dummy  ->          Value
#               M1      0
#               M2      0
#               M3      0
```

Then I read a file and create some batches and compare the name in the batch with the stored names in dictionary. If it doesn't exist, a new key-value (name and dataframe) is created. Otherwise, the Value column is appended to the existing dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.batch.csv')
print(df)
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
    print("\n------BATCH BEGIN")
    batch_df = df.iloc[i:i+3]
    name = batch_df.loc[i].at["Name"]
    values = batch_df.loc[:,"Value"]
    print(name)
    print(values)
    print("------BATCH END")
    if name in dict:
        # Append values to the existing key
        dict[name].join( values )
    else:
        # Create a new pair in dictionary
        dict[name] = values;
```

As you can see in the output, the join statement has error.

```
   ID Name Metric  Value
0   0   K1     M1     10
1   0   K1     M2      5
2   0   K1     M3     10
3   1   K2     M1     20
4   1   K2     M2     10
5   1   K2     M3     15
6   2   K1     M1      2
7   2   K1     M2      2
8   2   K1     M3      2

------BATCH BEGIN
K1
0    10
1     5
2    10
Name: Value, dtype: int64
------BATCH END

------BATCH BEGIN
K2
3    20
4    10
5    15
Name: Value, dtype: int64
------BATCH END

------BATCH BEGIN
K1
6    2
7    2
8    2
Name: Value, dtype: int64
------BATCH END
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_542/1252624065.py in <module>
     23     if name in dict:
     24         # Append values to the existing key
---> 25         dict[name].join( values )
     26     else:
     27         # Create a new pair in dictionary
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5485         ):
   5486             return self[name]
-> 5487         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5488 
   5489     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Change `values` to

```
values = batch_df.loc[:,["Value"]]
```

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 'Value')' is an invalid key` in the join statement.

Comment: Do you know how to fix that?